# Smart way to chain ifelse statements?

Tags: r, if-statement

When I have to chain ifelse statements, it looks like:

```
ifelse(input=="x","x1",
       ifelse(input=="y","x2",
              ifelse(input=="z","x3",NA)))
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? I'm thinking about creating tables then merging or something alike just to make the code look better?

Comment: Use a named vector or list, or look at `switch` or `factor`.

Comment: I find multiple ifelse chains more readable If you don't indent every new ifelse but instead add line break before `,NA)))`.

Comment: I would recommend using tables for anything but the simplest `ifelse` statements. Makes it easier to debug and to understand in future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apart from the suggestions in comments you could also use `match` in the following way.

Create sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
vals_in <- c("x", "y", "z")   # unique values in your input vector
vec_in <- sample(vals_in, 10, replace = TRUE)  # sample from vals_in to create input
vals_out <-  c("x1", "x2", "x3")  # values to replace
```

Now, to replace the nested `ifelse`s you could do:

```
vec_out <- vals_out[match(vec_in, vals_in)]
```

The result is

```
vec_out
# [1] "x1" "x2" "x2" "x3" "x1" "x3" "x3" "x2" "x2" "x1"
```

---

A little comparison of two approaches:

```
set.seed(1)
vals_in <- letters
vec_in <- sample(vals_in, 1e7, replace = TRUE)
vals_out <-  LETTERS

system.time(vals_out[match(vec_in, vals_in)])
       User      System verstrichen 
      0.378       0.020       0.398 
system.time(unname(setNames(vals_out, vals_in)[vec_in]))
       User      System verstrichen 
      1.020       0.062       1.084
```

Comment: This is cool. But any suggestion how to deal with other type conditions like inequalities?

Comment: @Pekka, an small example would be nice to test it. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: Well I was thinking something like this: `x = 1:14;
ifelse(x==5,'a',
ifelse(x %in% c(1,4),'b',
ifelse(x <= 10,'c',
ifelse(x <= 12,'d',
'e'))))`

Comment: Good comparison, plus one.

Comment: @Pekka, I think it would be much more difficult with such a problem but that equally applies to all the other answers here. In the end, there's a reason why `ifelse` exists. If it were easily replaced with a single other function it probably wouldn't exist in the first place

Comment: @docendodiscimus Ok. Yes I agree. Just took a chance in case you had some more secret knowledge about ifelses :). Didn't mean to criticize your answer, it's very nice and solves the problem!

Comment: @Pekka, that's alright, I didn't feel critized and it was a valid question

Answer (score 8):

You can try a function like this one:

```
choice <- function(input) {
  switch(input,
         "x"="x1",
         "y"="x2",
         "z"="x3",
         NA)
}
#> choice("x")
#[1] "x1"
#> choice("z")
#[1] "x3"
#> choice("other")
#[1] NA
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus One could wrap this function into `sapply()` to treat an input vector, like this: `sapply(my_vector, choice)`, but I assume that this would not yield a very fast performance.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be using `setNames`

```
unname(setNames(vals_out, vals_in)[vec_in])
#[1] "x1" "x2" "x2" "x3" "x1" "x3" "x3" "x2" "x2" "x1"
```

NOTE: Taken the example from @docendo discimus post.