# Using ifelse to match within a vector in R

Tags: r

I'm confused as to why this isn't working..?

```
getArea <- function(x){

  x <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "_"), "[[", 2)
  x <- substr(x,1,2)

  out <- ifelse( x == "PL", x <- "PO",
      ifelse( x == "PH", x <- "PO",
       ifelse( x == "CM", x <- "CP",
        ifelse( x == "EP", x <- "PE",
         ifelse( x == "EW", x <- "PE",
          ifelse( x == "VD", x <- "VM",
           ifelse( x == "VE", x <- "VM",
            ifelse( x == "BA", x <- "VM",
             ifelse( x == "TP", x <- "YD",
              x <- "NA")))))))))
  x <- out
}

p <- c("aa_VD","aa_CM","aa_PH","aa_PL4","aa_EP","aa_EW","aa_VE1","aa_TP","aa_VA")
Areas <- getArea(p)
```

It should match and return a vector of the matches...but its only seeing the first match in the ifelse option list and bringing back NAs for all other elements..?

Comment: I tried switch and still couldn't get the result I wanted..?

Comment: You don't need the `x<-` inside the `ifelse` call i.e. `ifelse(x=="PL", "PO", ifelse(x=="CM", "CP", ...` also if there are multiple elements to be assigned to a single one, use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: You don't need a single `ifelse` here. Just create two vectors and use something like `match` or similar. Your function will get slower and cumbersome as you add values. It's already probably very slow.

Comment: thanks akun - couldn't see wood for trees

Comment: In other words, try `lookup <- c("PL", "PH", "CM", "EP", "EW", "VD", "VE", "BA", "TP");
replace <- c(rep("PO", 2), "CP", rep("PE", 2), rep("VM", 3), "YD");
replace[match(gsub(".*_|\\d+", "", p), lookup)]`

Comment: Here's a somewhat similar Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336536/smart-way-to-chain-ifelse-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your function a bit, based on akrun's comment under your question.

```
getArea <- function(x) {
      x <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "_"), "[[", 2)
      x <- substr(x, 1, 2)

      out <- ifelse(x %in% c("PL", "PH"), "PO",
               ifelse(x == "CM",  "CP",
                 ifelse(x %in% c("EP", "EW") ,  "PE",
                   ifelse(x %in% c("VD", "VE", "BA"), "VM",
                     ifelse(x == "TP",  "YD", NA)
                           ))))
      return(out)
}

p <- c("aa_VD","aa_CM","aa_PH","aa_PL4","aa_EP","aa_EW","aa_VE1","aa_TP","aa_VA")
getArea(p)
[1] "VM" "CP" "PO" "PO" "PE" "PE" "VM" "YD" NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with named vectorelements:

```
L <- c(PL="PO", PH="PO", CM="CP", EP="PE",
       EW="PE", VD="VM", VE="VM", BA="VM", TP="YD")
p <- c("aa_VD","aa_CM","aa_PH","aa_PL4","aa_EP","aa_EW","aa_VE1","aa_TP","aa_VA")                            
Areas <- L[substr(p, 4,5)]
```